# The 'infavorites' search query is broken on Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, search, stackexchange.com

I'm pretty sure this link worked some day in the past: https://stackexchange.com/search?q=infavorites%3Amine+

It should only display your favorites from all Stack Exchange sites. Instead, the filter is not working, so I consider this to be a bug. This query works on every Stack Exchange site, except for stackexchange.com, itself.

If this isn't a bug, I still think this should be the expected behavior. I know a question that I marked as favorite, but I don't remember on which site I've seen the question, since we have many Stack Exchange sites that are related to each other (i.e. Stack Overflow, Super User, etc.)

Comment: No, it never worked. What you remember is probably the Filtered Questions, which has a built-in "Favorite Tags" filter which is doing what you want.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask thanks for the reply, but the Filtered Questions cannot display only my fav questions nor search through them. However, the linked duplicate is exactly what I'd like to support.

Comment: Don't you see "favorite tags" link in the sidebar [here](https://stackexchange.com/filters)?

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask I do, but this is not what I want. I want to search through all my marked favorite questions (bookmarks) from all pages, not my favorite tags. But as I said previously, the question you linked is the right one, so my question has been closed, rightfully.

Comment: Oh sorry, got confused, thought you meant favorite tags all along while you mean bookmarked questions - my bad. Cheers! :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask all good, I set up a bounty on the question that got linked and received a solution that I can live with, I really manage to hit 0 rep soon, again, haha. */me facepalm* :)